# make clicking chrome notification bring chrome window to front?

Tags: google-chrome, notifications, focus

Nothing seems to work. I guess it's designed this way to stop popups. But i really want to bring the chrome browser window ( say for instance behind firefox or word) to the front when the notification is clicked.

```
window.focus()
parent.focus()
```

do not work. I cant seem to find any way to actually move the chrome window to the front. Any suggestions?
Even if there was some way to make it request users permission once to do this, then do it automatically after that. I would be fine about it.